# Is it possible to call a method with the parameter of 'lambda expression'?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Let's say I have a method with the following signature:

```
public string Foo(Expression expression)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to call this method directly, without using proxy methods, and if it is, how?

As a bonus question (to understand why am I trying to do this), is it possible to declare a single method (without overloads) which will be called in all these cases:

```
Foo(P p => "");
Foo((P p, Q q) => "");
Foo((P p, Q q, R r) => "");
```

The reason I'm trying to write this in a single method is because I'm only interested in the lambda expression parameter to parse it in some way, not to execute it.

Comment: Care to comment on a downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call this method directly you need to cast expression you pass to specific expression delegate type. For example:

```
Foo((Expression<Func<P, string>>) ((P p) => ""));
Foo((Expression<Func<P, Q, string>>) ((P p, Q q) => ""));
Foo((Expression<Func<P, Q, R, string>>) ((P p, Q q, R r) => ""));
Expression<Func<P, string>> x = (P p) => "";
Foo(x); // also fine
```

The reason is otherwise compiler cannot infer type of delegate to use. Expression `(P p) => ""` has no type by itself, type is determined by the context. If you use it in context where delegate is expected, and it's compatible - it will be a delegate:

```
Func<P, string> x = (P p) => "";
MyDelegate x = (P p) => "";
```

If you use it in context where expression tree of specific delegate type is expected - it will be expression tree:

```
Expression<Func<P, string>> x = (P p) => "";
```

But in your case - its type cannot be inferred. It can be `Expression<Func<P, string>>`, `Expression<MyCustomDelegate>` or anything else. Different delegate types are not the same, even if they have the same signature. So you have to tell it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explains it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, You can use as follows,

```
Foo(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query)
{
      // implementation
}
```

call it as

```
Foo((x=> x.bar == 1));
```

you don't need to use overloads in above-mentioned method calls. use this method instead and pass whatever the lambda you want.

hope it helps :)

Comment: But this is an expression with a single input and a single output. I don't see how this would match the examples the OP has with two or three input parameters....

Comment: you can create an entity with the parameters you want to pass and pass that to the lambda ...

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `delegate` with the `params` keyword.

Example:

```
public delegate void ParamsAction(params object[] args);
```

Then:

```
public void Foo(object[] args)
{
  ...
}
```

To use:

```
ParamsAction action = Foo;
action(p);
action(p, q);
action(p, q, r);
```

or:

```
ParamsAction action1 = p => "";
ParamsAction action2 = p, q => "";
ParamsAction action3 = p, q, r => "";
```

Comment: This way I wouldn't have properties of P, Q and R, because they would all be objects, right? So, variables p, q and r wouldn't be able to reference the properties of classes P, Q and R?

Comment: Yes, you're right, you could add some logic in the Foo(objects[] args) method to get those properties out. The problem is that Func<T, TResult> and Action<T> are not able to take a variable number of arguments, so this is one way to solve your problem short of overloading your Foo method to take different parameters.